# Screen flicker -- Dell Inspiron 15

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, display

The screen on my Dell Inspiron 15 has a high frequency `slight' flicker to it, especially around the edges of the screen. The pattern of the flickery areas is symmetric.

It has GeForce GTX 1050Ti graphics card, nvidia drivers version 390.30 (up to date).

The flicker is not present when in virtual console (ctrl+alt+f1).

I have attempted to use nvidia-xconfig to see whether xconf.org settings are the issue, however the automatically generated settings were inadequate.

How to troubleshoot this?